Cannot resolve symbol 'embedding' in flutter
I have an Android Project Studio, with MainActivity.java class on which I want to add a flutter screen. I generated and built my flutter-module, included the dependencies. Sync works, but when I import  io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine, it keeps saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'embedding'." I unzipped the jar files and looked into the jar to see if the embedding is in io.flutter, but it is not there, I have no idea what else to do.

Did you already try the answer from this question?
